# Browser caching Requests with different Datatypes

Tags: jquery, json, http, caching

I am trying to get two different resources, that are at the same URI, but have different datatypes.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "application/json",
  url: "http://www.myApp.com/resource",
  success: f
});

$.ajax({
  dataType: "text/html",
  url: "http://www.myApp.com/resource",
  success: f
});
```

But the second call never leaves the browser. The result of the first call is cached and returned to the second call. 
But it has the wrong datatype! json vs html.
I do not know whether it is cached by jquery or the browser (chrome)?

Is there a way to make this work? I need both representations of the resource.
I could set the cache to false in the requests, but then I would lose the benefit of caching.

Or do I have to define two different resource URIs for the different representations?

Answer (score 0):

In dataType, replace `"application/json"` with `"json"` and `"text/html"` with `"html"`.
[jQuery recognizes](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) only the following as valid inputs:

- xml
- json
- jsonp
- html
- text
- script

Or a space-separated combination of some of the above. Any other value will result in a request with an `Accept` header of `*/*`.

Also, you might want to replace your `success` callback in favor of `$.ajax({...}).done(callback)`. The callback parameter was deprecated in 1.8.